# I need to run xrandr -o normal at startup and keep getting Bad Interpretation error

Tags: command-line, startup, xrandr, startup-applications, sh

All I need to run `xrandr -o normal` at startup and keep getting

```
Bad Interpretation error - No such file or directory exists.
```

This is the script I have:

```
#!bin/bash
xrandr -o normal
```

I've checked the location and its definitely there.

Comment: `#!bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash` (note the additional `/`)

Answer (score 3):

`bin/bash` lacks a leading `/` and is thus a [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths). It refers to `bash` in the `bin` subdirectory of *wherever you currently are*. Usually this simply does not exist, as in this case. When it does exist, it may not be the correct file.

It appears you intend an absolute path. As [steeldriver commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168864/i-need-to-run-xrandr-o-normal-at-startup-and-keep-getting-bad-interpretation-er#comment1950091_1168864), writing the leading `/` in the path will solve this problem, ensuring that the `bin` component of the path always refers to the `bin` directory residing directly in `/`.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You should not attempt to use a relative path in a [shebang/hashbang (`#!`) line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). In this case, it seems you didn't attempt to do so, but just ended up doing so by accident.

Sometimes people try to do this, writing things like `#!python3` with the hope that `PATH` lookup will occur as it does when running a command in the shell. It does not occur. (`#!/usr/bin/env python3` can be used in those cases because the `env` command searches `PATH`.)

*Unlike* with symbolic links whose targets are relative paths, where the target is resolved relative to the location where the symlink resides, [a relative path in a `#!` line is resolved relative to whatever happens to be the current working directory when the script is run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77584/11938). This is the case even when the relative path contains multiple path components separated by a `/` (e.g., `bin/bash`). That location won't typically be the same each time a script is run and it is very often not the directory containing the script.

So while symlinks with relative paths are often useful, shebangs with relative paths are in practice always a mistake.